# Checking for empty form fields with a Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, forms, loops

I'm trying to loop through a small form and check for blank fields. I thought it would be simple, but I'm not able to get anything to work. This is my Javascript so far:

```
var obj = {

fname : document.getElementsByName('fname'),
lname : document.getElementsByName('lname'),
phone : document.getElementsByName('phone'),
email : document.getElementsByName('email'),
span : document.createElement('span'),
txt : document.createTextNode('*Required Field'),



init : function(){
     document.getElementsByName('submit').onclick = obj.validate;
},

validate : function(){
     var check = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     var len = check.length;
     for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
     if (check[i].value ==='')
     {
          alert('required');
          return false;
     }; 

 };

  },

};
```

This is the HTML:

```
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<div>
<ul>
<li><label>First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" size="30"  /></li>
<li><label>Email</label><input type="text" name="email" size="30" /></li>
<li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">obj.init();</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

I thought i should be able to loop through the inputs and alert if the value was blank, but, it's not working for me. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: obj.check.length should be check.length. check.value should be check[i].value. You should really rename the check variable to something more descriptive, like inputElements.

Comment: @UkuleleFury woops. forgot to delete that obj. I was trying to have check be an object before putting in the function as a variable. But, i changed both of those and it's still not working. Thanks for the advice, though.

Comment: I edited my code to what i have now. It is still not working :/

Comment: @rexer What goes wrong exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @aw04 no errors. When i hit the submit button, the screen flashes. Now im thinking it might be submitting the form, but i thought return false would stop it from doing that.

Comment: @rexer If you don't get the alert though, you know it's never getting to return false.

Comment: @aw04 yeah, that's true. I just don't get why its not giving me the alert; everything looks right.

Comment: @rexer Just a tip: if your stuck add some more alerts or console logs to help pinpoint what code is being executed and where you might have an issue.

Comment: @aw04 i made it document.getElementsByName('submit').onclick = alert; and the alert popped up after i clicked the button, but it also popped up on the page load. I cant get an alert to pop up anywhere in the validate function.

Comment: @rexer: see my amended answer, below. getElementsByName() returns an array, so init() would not work as-is. It would make more sense to use getElementById() on an ID.

Comment: @cybersam ah, okay. I didnt know that getElementsByName() returned an array. I added an id, and im getting the alert now. Thanks! hopefully the other steps to this go smoother than this one did. ha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (after adding `id="submit"` attribute to your submit element):

```
  init : function(){
     document.getElementById('submit').onclick = obj.validate;
  },

  validate : function(){
     var check = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     var len = check.length;
     for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
       if (check[i].value ==='')
       {
          alert('required');
          return false;
       }; 
     };
  }
```

Comment: still getting nothing. This looks like it should work though. Thanks for trying to help me out.

Comment: See my amended answer. You were using an array improperly. You could use getElementById() on an ID instead.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (check.value ==='')
```

To

```
if (check[i].value ==='')
```

Comment: still not working. that was actually one of the things i tried earlier. Glad to see someone else thought it should work.haha.

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the object *check* and not *each element* in it. Do this

```
if(check[i].value === '')
```

Comment: I switched it to that, but it is still not working. Thanks for trying to help me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I believe it will work for you!

```js
var obj = {

fname : document.getElementsByName('fname'),
lname : document.getElementsByName('lname'),
phone : document.getElementsByName('phone'),
email : document.getElementsByName('email'),
span : document.createElement('span'),
txt : document.createTextNode('*Required Field'),



init : function(){
     document.getElementsByName('submit').onclick = obj.validate;
},

validate : function(){
     var check = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     var filteredCheckArray = Array.from(check).filter( input =>{
          return input.value.length === 0;
     }
     );
     if (filteredCheckArray.length !== 0)
     {
          alert('required');
          return false;
     }; 

  },

};
```